# Architecture pattern in React for datas between parent and children

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

In my React app, I meet very often this kind of architecture:

```
<Parent>
   <Child1 />
   ...
   <ChildN />
</Parent>
```

with data shared between Parent and Child(s). If I want to get the Child(s) independent, I have to let them get the data they need alone, but in this case I have redundancies between Parent and Child(s). If I build all required data once in the Parent and spread them in Child(s), I loose independence to satisfy DRY principle.

What are the different patterns I can use in this case?
To be precise, I don't need a way of passing data between the component or stocking them (Redux, Context, localStorage, etc.) but a way of organizing code and files.
And I don't want "the best solution" (that doesn't exist) but all the possible solutions, to let me test them and find what is appropriate in my case.